# Pass in db password to Groovy

Tags: java, linux, unix, groovy

I'm trying to find a way to pass in a database (Oracle) password that's stored in an environment variable ($PSWD) to a Groovy program running on Linux or Unix such that when I run the ps command and grep on the job name it does not show the password.  All of our Groovy programs are currently executed as java programs via shell scripts (ksh right now) like so:

```
java group.JOBNAME $UID $PSWD
```

But of course if we simply pass in the password as an argument, we can see what that password is by running ps.  Any ideas?

Comment: ...read the environment variable?

Comment: Thanks for all the down votes with no explanation!  That's awesome!  And yes, read the environment variable?  Oh, you mean like cfrick actually *explained* below.  Thank you cfrick!

Answer (score 2):

You can read the env var in groovy by e.g. `System.env.PSWD`. Don't pass it by command line argument!

Comment: Thanks cfrick!  I'm obviously new to java and groovy.  I showed this to my manager and although he likes it, he'd rather that we "pipe in the password".  I don't really know how to do that and some google searching didn't help me so I'll move forward with your suggestion.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is it better to have it in an environment variable than on the command line?  Isn't it amazingly accessible either way?